# how to get local ip not public ip in django?

Tags: python, django, networking

so i have this website to manage the local network of my business i have 2 project inside it one is the callback server one is the main app that manage the local network. so i want to restrict to only people that can access the technician router can access the main app.  i already make the view to get the client ip address but it return public ip but what i want is ip address that the user is connected that is in range "192.178.1.x ~ 192.178.50", can anyone help me?, if anyone have suggestion how can i used different method for this cases please just share it out. thanks :) here's code

views.py

```
def ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    print(ip)
    return HttpResponse(ip)
```

Comment: sorry if people get confused my question i edited the question, thing i try to do is get the client ip address that in range i set

Answer (score 1):

Your local IP can be found in python with the following code:

```
import socket
local_ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
print(local_ip)
```

I don't know much about Django, but hopefully you can implement this snippet in your code.

Comment: but  that only get my server ip..mate if i deploy it but what i want is the ip of the host that connected, but thanks for replying to my question :)

Comment: @wika sorry I misunderstood your question.